# iOS5 how can I reference my application logic objects from within storyboard

Tags: design-patterns, ios5, storyboard

I am wandering which is the best practice to have a reference of the objects managing the logic of my application so that I can obtain data or perform operations on them from the view controllers.

I am new to iOS development, I have some experience in Java an what I did was to inject a reference of the objects I were interested in when I built the controllers.

Using storyboard the creation of controllers is not managed directly by me, so I have some issues in finding a way to have model-controller interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Core Data to store your data. Learning to use it take some time, but once you figure it out it provides an excellent way to store and access your application data. This tutorial should get you started:
[Core Data Tutorial for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Also, for a simpler method when you have a small amount of data look at the way data is stored and accessed in the program attached to this issue:
[DataModel example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430888/adding-data-to-tableview-using-delegate-fail/8432290#8432290)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll have a look at it.