# How to add data to tableview using a delegate?

Tags: uitableview, delegates, ios5, storyboard

I'm building an app for fun with a initial view controller of a tableview, where you are able to see the details of the cells, and add new data to the tableview.

**First off, here is the project, so you can load it and have a look.**
http://dawtano.com/xc-project.zip

It's a bit of a complex project and I think much of the code is obsolete, but the initial app is working, so I don't want to clean it up just yet.

The app is built around storyboard and consists of:

- DataModel (containing the initial NSMutableArray)
- ViewController (main view)
- EditGrade (adding data to the tableview)
- Grade (defining the strings used)
- GradeDetail (showing details of the cell)

EditGrade also contains a delegate which add function to the Cancel and Done button.

Everything works (except the Edit button on GradeDetail) as it should, except when I try and add new data to the tableview. The project builds with no issues.
This is the error message I get and I haven't been able to figure out what the issue is:

```
2011-12-08 12:56:54.643 ArrayTableView[30711:f803] *** Assertion failure in -    
[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _computeRowUpdates], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-     
1912.3/UITableViewSupport.m:386
2011-12-08 12:56:54.645 ArrayTableView[30711:f803] *** 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Invalid table view update.  The application has requested an update to 
the table view that is inconsistent with the state provided by the data source.'
```

I hope some of you will be able to determine what the issue is, I'm currently staring myself blind on it.

**Update**
Thanks to @T.J. I found the mistake in the project, the problem now is implementing it correct, so addGrade works.

I added this code in the field @T.J. pointed out:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:
(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
// Delete the row from the data source
[self.dataModel removeGradeAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}   
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
// Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, 
and add a new  row to the table view
[self.dataModel addGrade:(Grade*)grades];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}   
}
```

Am I using the correct coding? I have a feeling

```
[self.dataModel addGrade:(Grade*)grades];
```

is incorrect. Since the DataModel uses:

```
- (void)addGrade:(Grade*)grade
{
[self.grades addObject:grade];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Matias If you are going to insert rows to the table you need to this code section:

```
 else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
[self.dataModel addGrade ...
[tableView insertRowAtIndexPaths ...
```

The code will be similar to the code you wrote above that to delete a row in the table:

```
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 // Delete the row from the data source
 [self.dataModel removeGradeAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }
```

Comment: Oh wow, I'm amazed I didn't find that mistake. Although it still does not work, I know where the mistake was: I just updated my question to reflect the current situation, I hope you can help me solve it.

Comment: You still have several problems. One is that your addGrade needs to look more like this: - (void)addGrade:(NSString *)faq multilig:(NSString *)multilig 
{
// grade.gradeId = nextId++;
    Grade *grade = [[Grade alloc] init];
    grade.fag = faq;
    grade.mundtlig = multilig;
 [self.grades addObject:grade];
}

Comment: I don't understand that, why do I need to change the addGrade method and include two nsstrings in it, when all that is needed is to add one or more strings to the nsmutablearray grades.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't afford the time to help you further on this.